# Haskell Deriving Mechanism for Agda

Tags: haskell, signature, agda

I am wondering if there is anything in Agda that resembles Haskell's `deriving Eq` clause ---then I have an associated question below, as well.

For example, suppose I have types for a toy-language,

```
data Type : Set where
  Nat  : Type
  Prp : Type
```

Then I can implement decidable equality by pattern matching and `C-c C-a`,

```
_≟ₜ_ : Decidable {A = Type} _≡_
Nat ≟ₜ Nat = yes refl
Nat ≟ₜ Prp = no (λ ())
Prp ≟ₜ Nat = no (λ ())
Prp ≟ₜ Prp = yes refl
```

I'm curious if this can be mechanised or automated somehow similar to the manner it is done in Haskell:

```
data Type = Nat | Prp deriving Eq
```

Thank-you!

While we're on the topic of types, I'd like to realise my formal types as Agda types: Nat is just natural numbers while Prp is small propositions.

```
⟦_⟧Type : Type → Set ?
⟦ Nat ⟧Type = ℕ
⟦ Prp ⟧Type = Set
```

Sadly this does not work. I tried to fix this with lifting but failed since I haven't a clue on how to use level lifting. Any help is appreciated!

An example usage of the above function would be,

```
record InterpretedFunctionSymbol : Set where
  field
   arity   : ℕ
   src tgt : Type
   reify   : Vec ⟦ src ⟧Type arity → ⟦ tgt ⟧Type
```

Thank-you for humouring me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "7.3.2. Deriving operations on datatypes" chapter of [A Cosmology of Datatypes](https://pages.lip6.fr/Pierre-Evariste.Dagand/stuffs/thesis-2011-phd/thesis.pdf) shows how to derive operations using descriptions. Though, the derived `Eq` is rather weak there.

The basic idea is to represent data types using some first-order encoding, i.e. in terms of some generic data type, and define operations on this data type, so everything encoded in terms of it can be handled by these generic operations. I elaborated a simple version of this machinery [here](http://effectfully.blogspot.ru/2016/02/simple-generic-programming.html).

You can derive a stronger `Eq`, if you have a closed universe. Using a similar to descriptions approach (should be equally expressive, but I didn't check) and a closed universe I defined generic `show` [here](https://github.com/effectfully/OTT/blob/master/Property/Showable.agda), which allows e.g. to print a vector of tuples after you name the constructors:

```
instance
  named-vec : {A : Type} -> Named (vec-cs A)
  named-vec = record { names = "nil" ∷ "cons" ∷ [] }

test₂ : show (Vec (nat & nat) 3 ∋ (7 , 8) ∷ᵥ (9 , 10) ∷ᵥ (11 , 12) ∷ᵥ []ᵥ)
      ≡ "(cons 2 (7 , 8) (cons 1 (9 , 10) (cons 0 (11 , 12) nil)))"
test₂ = prefl
```

where `Vec` is defined in terms of a similar to `Desc` data type. The `Eq` case should be similar, but more sophisticated.

Here is how `Lift` can be used:

```
⟦_⟧Type : Type → Set₁
⟦ Nat ⟧Type = Lift ℕ
⟦ Prp ⟧Type = Set

ex₁ : ∀ A -> ⟦ A ⟧Type
ex₁ Nat = lift 0
ex₁ Prp = ℕ

ex₂ : ∀ A -> ⟦ A ⟧Type -> Maybe ℕ
ex₂ Nat n = just (lower n) -- or (ex₂ Nat (lift n) = just n)
ex₂ Prp t = nothing
```

If `A : Set α` then `Lift A : Set (α ⊔ ℓ)` for any `ℓ`. So when you have `ℕ : Set` and `Set : Set₁`, you want to lift `ℕ` from `Set` to `Set₁`, which is just `Lift ℕ` — in simple cases you don't need to provide `ℓ` explicitly.

To construct an element of a data type wrapped in `Lift` you use `lift` (like in `lift 0`). And to get this element back you use `lower`, so `lift` and `lower` are inverses of each other. Note though that `lift (lower x)` doesn't necessarily lie in the same universe as `x`, because `lift (lower x)` "refreshes" `ℓ`.

**UPDATE**: the `show` link is broken now (I should have used a permalink). But there is a better example now: [an entire library](https://github.com/effectfully/Generic/) that derives `Eq` for regular Agda data types.

Comment: Thank-you very much; I look forwards to reading the cited thesis and cited blog ^_^

Answer (score 3):

For a practical implementation of "deriving Eq" in Agda, you can take a look at Ulf's agda-prelude at https://github.com/UlfNorell/agda-prelude. In particular, the module Tactic.Deriving.Eq contains code for automatically generating decidable equality for a quite general class of (simple and indexed) data types.

Comment: Is it able to derive `Eq (Vec A n)` having `Eq A` in scope?